# Finding the average an object field for each key within a map

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary, hashmap, average

I currently have a map (shown below) `<Object, ArrayList<Object>>`. This contains the object Observatory which is connected an arrayList of Earthquake objects. What I am aiming to do is find the average value of the Earthquake attribute "magnitude" within each ArrayList, returning an average magnitude for each key(Observatory).

```
  public static ArrayList<Observatory> obsList = new ArrayList<>();
  public static ArrayList<Earthquake> quakeList = new ArrayList<>();

  public static Map<Observatory, ArrayList<Earthquake>> eqMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I then hope to return the name of the Observatory that has the highest value for average magnitude.

I populate my ArrayList using the following code:

```
    public static void mapQuakeToObs(String o, Earthquake e) {

          //Earthquake object contains String "o" to define its assigned observatory

        for (Observatory obs : obsList) {

            if(obs.getObsname().equals(o)) {

                Observatory x = obs;

                if (!eqMap.containsKey(o)) { 
                    eqMap.put(x, new ArrayList<Earthquake>()); 
                }
                eqMap.get(x).add(e);

            }                                               
        }           
    }
```

So what I am looking for is a way to calculate the average magnitude of the earthquakes assigned to each Observatory key, returning the Observatory key with the largest average.

Comment: How is the Earthquake-class structured? If you want to calculate the average magnitude, then it has an magnitude attribute?

Comment: `Observatory x = obs;` seems redundant, and it may be more efficient to fill the arraylist before it is added to the map. Simplicity does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your Earthquake and Observatory classes look like, but I'll assume they look something like this:

```
Earthquake:

    public class Earthquake {

    private final String obsname;
    private final float magnitude;

    public Earthquake(String obsname, float magnitude) {
        this.obsname = obsname;
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
    }

    public float getMagnitude() {
        return magnitude;
    }

    public String getObsname() {
        return obsname;
    }
}
```

Observatory:

```
public class Observatory {

    private final String obsname;

    public Observatory(String obsname) {
        this.obsname = obsname;
    }

    public String getObsname() {
        return obsname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return obsname;
    }
}
```

Create a method to return the average magnitude of a list of Earthquakes:

```
public static float findAverageMagnitude(List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
    float total = 0.0f;
    for(Earthquake earthquake : earthquakes) {
        total += earthquake.getMagnitude();
    }
    return total / earthquakes.size();
}
```

Modify the method you show in your question to return a map with String keys, where each value is a List of Earthquakes:

```
    public static Map<String, List<Earthquake>> mapQuakeToObs(
            List<Observatory> obsList, List<Earthquake> quakes) {

        Map<String, List<Earthquake>> obsAndQuakes =
                new HashMap<String, List<Earthquake>>();
        //Earthquake object contains String "o" to define its assigned observatory
        for(Earthquake quake : quakes) {
            for (Observatory obs : obsList) {

                if (obs.getObsname().equals(quake.getObsname())) {
                    List<Earthquake> quakesMappedToObs = null;
                    // If the map doesn't already contain the key, then put it there
                    if(!obsAndQuakes.containsKey(obs.getObsname())) {
                        quakesMappedToObs = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
                        obsAndQuakes.put(obs.getObsname(), quakesMappedToObs);
                    } else {
                        quakesMappedToObs = obsAndQuakes.get(obs.getObsname());
                    }
                    quakesMappedToObs.add(quake);
                }
            }
        }
        return obsAndQuakes;
    }
```

Finally, call these methods in another method like so, to see which Observatory has the highest average of Earthquake magnitudes:

```
public static Observatory findObservatoryWithHighestAverageMagnitude(
            List<Observatory> observatories, List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {

        float highestRecordedAverage = 0.0f;
        String obsnameWithHighestRecordedAverage = null;
        Map<String, List<Earthquake>> obsAndQuakes
                = mapQuakeToObs(observatories, earthquakes);
        for(String obsName: obsAndQuakes.keySet()) {
            List<Earthquake> quakesMappedToObs = obsAndQuakes.get(obsName);
            float averageMagnitude = findAverageMagnitude(quakesMappedToObs);
            if(averageMagnitude > highestRecordedAverage) {
                highestRecordedAverage = averageMagnitude;
                obsnameWithHighestRecordedAverage = obsName;
            }

        }
        for(Observatory observatory : observatories) {
            if(observatory.getObsname().equals(obsnameWithHighestRecordedAverage)) {
                return observatory;
            }
        }
        //This code won't be reached
        return null;
    }
```

Now, watch it in action:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observatory observatory1 = new Observatory("Observatory One");
        Observatory observatory2 = new Observatory("Observatory Two");
        Earthquake quake1a = new Earthquake("Observatory One", 0.1f);
        Earthquake quake1b = new Earthquake("Observatory One", 7.9f);
        Earthquake quake1c = new Earthquake("Observatory One", 8.3f);
        Earthquake quake2a = new Earthquake("Observatory Two", 3.2f);
        Earthquake quake2b = new Earthquake("Observatory Two", 2.9f);
        Earthquake quake2c = new Earthquake("Observatory Two", 4.7f);
        List<Observatory> observatories = new ArrayList<Observatory>();
        observatories.add(observatory1);
        observatories.add(observatory2);
        List<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
        earthquakes.add(quake1a);
        earthquakes.add(quake1b);
        earthquakes.add(quake1c);
        earthquakes.add(quake2a);
        earthquakes.add(quake2b);
        earthquakes.add(quake2c);
        // Prints "Observatory One"
        System.out.println(findObservatoryWithHighestAverageMagnitude(
                observatories, earthquakes));
    }
```

Comment: This is a working answer - 

This worked perfectly and I was able to get it to integrate nicely with the functionality of the program as a whole. You have all of my thanks!